# How do you align text vertically inside a container regardless of # of links inside them?

Tags: html, css, html-helper, centering

I need some assistance and I've tried almost everything I know. What I am trying to do (and it doesn't matter if I have to use tables on order to achieve this)

http:// img602.imageshack.us/img602/8769/verticalcentering .jpg

I've looked online and tried out several examples but they all seem to blow up or not align properly in IE.

What I need (if its possible, I don't even know anymore) is to have text links that will align vertically within the container its in regardless of whether there is only one link present, or four.

What's been happening is that when I set the margin to 50% it centers fine if there is only one link there, but the remainder will fall below it no longer centering the links within the container.

The actual thing I am working on is this:

I have a header title above that stretches across the container. The next row I have an image on the left that is 150px by 150px - and next to that I have another container that has a height of 150px as well as this is the maximum height of this container - inside this container is where I would like my links to hang out vertically centered.

Is this even possible? or is it a pipe dream to think it will work in IE and is cross browser compliant?

It doesn't matter anymore if I have to resort to tables and css to achieve this... I just need some assistance with it as I have never had to vertically center anything depending on its content before and I just can't wrap my head around how to achieve this effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)  Thanks in advance!

HERE IS THE CSS AND HTML BELOW

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Link Module</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.wrapper { height: 210px; width: 538px; background-color: #FFCCFF; }
.header { height: 47px; border-bottom: thin dotted #666; }
.txt-style {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: bold;
color: #666666;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: normal;
display: block;
}
.cos-sl-txt-cntr-two {
height: 150px;
}
.cos-sl-txt-cntr-two ul {
height: 150px;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}
.cos-sl-txt-cntr-two li {
margin-top: 50%;
margin-bottom: auto;
}
cos-sl-img-two {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #FF0033;
}
.learn-txt, .leader-txt {
color: #FF6666;
font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0; 
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 10px;
letter-spacing: .75px;
}
.leader-txt {
color: #fff;
font-size: 23px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 0px;
line-height: 24px; 
letter-spacing: -0.25px; 
}
.img-ctnr, .img-ctnr-two {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
float: left;
padding-left: 12px;
}
/* IMAGE LOCATION */
.img-two {
width: 150px;
height: 150px; 
display: block;
background-color: #FF99CC;
border: solid 3px #CCC; 
}
.txt-cntr, .txt-cntr-two {
width: 406px;
height: 126px;
float: left;
}
.txt-cntr-two {
width: 250px; 
height: 150px;
padding-left: 50px;
background-color:#CC99CC; 
}
.txt-pos {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 50px; 
padding-left: 20px; 
}
/* NAME TEXT/TITLE TEXT */
.name-txt, .info-txt, .name-txt-title, .info-txt-link {
font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #003466; 
margin: 0;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-left: 13px;
}
.sl-name-txt-title {
color: #666;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold; 
}
/* INFO TEXT/TEXT LINK OVER-RIDE */
.info-txt, .info-txt-link {
    padding-top: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1; 
}
.info-txt-link a {
    color: #003466;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
/* Hover State for the web links */
.info-txt-link a:hover {
    color: #ED1B24;
    text-decoration: none; 
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--CONTAINER HOLDING THE HEADER ELEMENTS-->
        <div class="header">
            <p class="learn-txt">Title</p>
            <p class="leader-txt">Subtitle</p>        
        </div>
        <div class="img-ctnr-two">
            <div class="img-two">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="txt-pos">
            <p class="name-txt-title">Canada</p>
            <p class="info-txt-link"><a href="#">www.mylinkhere.com</a></p>                 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide code that replicates this in a jsfiddle? It makes solving this type of stuff far easier. Also, what you want is located @ http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Vertical-Centering

Comment: post the code you are working with, that way we don't have to recreate all the HTML.

Comment: @meder: Not kidding, I hope you get a book deal soon with O'Reilly or someone.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It does everything else that I've tried. Centering it within its own container is not the issue. I am trying to center it inside a main container with a height of 150px so that if there is one link present it will center. If the user adds two links (CMS system) it will center, or if they add 4 it will center inside the main container which is set at a height of 150px

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 5em;
}
.outer .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        ABC
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        ABC<br>ABC
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        ABC<br>ABC<br>ABC
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It does everything else that I've tried. Centering it within its own container is not the issue. I am trying to center it inside a main container with a height of 150px so that if there is one link present it will center. If the user adds two links (CMS system) it will center, or if they add 4 it will center inside the main container which is set at a height of 150px